# want to use only one user define function for input and output in python 3+

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, user-defined-functions

```
from numpy import*
def row():
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a[i])):
            t = [i, j]
            inp(*t)
def inp(*m):
    a[m] = int(input(f"entert the element of {m} = "))
    out(*m)
def out(*o):
    print(a[o])
a = zeros((1,2), dtype = int)
row()
```

Output is showing like this:

```
enter the element of (0, 0) = 2
2
enter the element of (0, 1) = 3
3
```

but I want to show output like this

input at a time like this

```
enter the element of (0, 0) = 2
enter the element of (0, 1) = 3
```

output at a time like this

```
2
3
```

it is possible to do by creating two separate for loop or two function for input and output
but my question is: how can i do it only creating one function

```
def row():
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a[i])):
            t = [i, j]
            inp(*t)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing the output right away, save the values and print them after you've finished collecting them:

```py
import numpy as np

def row(a):
    values = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a[i])):
            value = get_input(a, i, j)
            values.append(value)
    for value in values:
        print(value)

def get_input(a, *m):
    a[m] = int(input(f"enter the element of {m} = "))
    return a[m]

a = np.zeros((1,2), dtype = int)
row(a)
```

gives

```
enter the element of (0, 0) = 1
enter the element of (0, 1) = 2
1
2
```

However, there's an even simpler way: since you also set the new elements in your matrix, you don't have to save them separately but can simply print out the matrix values:

```py
for item in a.ravel():
    print(item)
```

Comment: Thank you very much dear, actually I am very new in python programming, keep me in your prayer's